# White Bug when I want to edit in chat

Tags: support, chat

Pictures speak louder than words.

[image]

When it comes to editing the comment, the white font (why white?) makes it virtually impossible to see what I am doing. If I highlight the text, I can't edit because the highlighting then disappears.

Comment: Are you using extensions or add-ons? Some extensions cause it. Try disabling them one by one.

Comment: What extensions? You mean on Chrome?

Comment: Chrome extensions / Firefox addons. Same concept. They can interfere in the chat.

Comment: @NVZ  You were right! The bug has been fixed. Just turned off the addon  permanently. Well done! Culprit: Grammarly, good for my poor punctuation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some Chrome extensions or Firefox add-ons can interfere and cause this bug. Disabling those add-ons can solve this.